# Is there a way which helps the keyboard focus correctly on the textformfield

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield, lost-focus

I write an android app with flutter. As a part of my code I created a user page to let the user to update their information such as name surname or something like that.

It is working but when I clicked the page I am getting few errors.

1 is I/ple.flutter_ap(18747): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.

2nd is W/ple.flutter_ap(18747): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (light greylist, reflection)

And the other problem is The keyboard is not focusing on the textfield. When I clicked the textfield the keyborad is Opening and closing immediately. When I clicked again it shows up and again closing immediately.

I tried autofocus: true  but this time it tried to focus it self. It is opended and closed 5 times but at last it focused. But that shouldnt be happen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {


  var _AdContr = TextEditingController();
  var _SoyadContr = TextEditingController();
  final _NicknameContr = TextEditingController();
  final _getContr = TextEditingController();
  final _myUpdateContr = TextEditingController();

  var _transactionListener;

  @override
  void dispose() {
     // Clean up controllers when disposed
    _AdContr.dispose();
    _SoyadContr.dispose();
    _NicknameContr.dispose();
    _getContr.dispose();
    _myUpdateContr.dispose();
    // Cancel transaction listener subscription
    _transactionListener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  void clickUpdate(_formKey1, _formKey2) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String uid = user.uid.toString();
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('kitaplar')
        .document(uid)
        .updateData({'adi': _formKey1, 'Soyadi': _formKey2});
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


  }    





   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
                  return Container();
                return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('kitaplar')
                      .document(snapshot.data.uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
                    var userDocument = snapshot.data;
                    var contentadi = userDocument["adi"].toString();
                    var contentsoyadi = userDocument["Soyadi"].toString();

                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _AdContr = new TextEditingController(text: contentadi == null ? "" : contentadi),
                          //controller: _AdContr,
                          //initialValue: userDocument["adi"].toString(),
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Adınız',
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _SoyadContr = new TextEditingController(text: contentsoyadi == null ? "" : contentsoyadi),
                          //controller: _AdContr,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Soyadınız',
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                          child: const Text('Update'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            clickUpdate(_AdContr.text, _SoyadContr.text);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              })
      )
  );
}
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To foucs on next text input field you have to use "`FocusNode();`" such as below:
In the "TextFormField(" we can use this method to focus:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (v){
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
},
```

Also to set different options for text input field such as next and done options in keyboard, you can use below method:

1) For next option: "textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,"

2) For done option: "textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,"

Below is the full example to auto focus on next text input field:

```
class MyApp extends State<MyLoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final focus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
            child: Form(

              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 65.0, right: 30, bottom: 0),
                    child:
                    TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter username', contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      onFieldSubmitted: (v){
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 30.0, right: 30, bottom: 0),
                    child:
                    TextFormField(
                      focusNode: focus,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter password', contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      onFieldSubmitted: (v){
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),


                ],

              ),

            ),
        ),

    );
  }

}
```

**Problem is you are setting the text in TextFormField when keyboard opens with the TextEditingController.** It means 
you are assigning a value every time in TextEditingController so when keyboard opens, "TextEditingController" will
fire and it will try to check your condition and set the default value in your TextFormField and then keyboard gets
closed as normal behaviour.

So to solve this do as below:

First of all initialize your "TextEditingController" with "new" keyboard as below:

```
  var _AdContr = new TextEditingController();
  var _SoyadContr = new TextEditingController();
  final _NicknameContr = new TextEditingController();
  final _getContr = new TextEditingController();
  final _myUpdateContr = new TextEditingController();
```

Then try to set default text for "TextFormField" after this two lines:

```
var contentadi = userDocument["adi"].toString();
var contentsoyadi = userDocument["Soyadi"].toString();
_AdContr.text = (contentadi == null ? "" : contentadi);
_SoyadContr.text = (contentsoyadi == null ? "" : contentsoyadi);
```

Then change your "TextFormField" as below and try to save those value in your variables in "onSubmitted" method:

```
return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _AdContr,
                          onSubmitted: (String str){
                            setState(() {
                                contentadi = str;
                                _AdContr.text = contentadi;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Adınız',
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _SoyadContr,
                          onSubmitted: (String str){
                            setState(() {
                                contentsoyadi = str;
                                _SoyadContr.text = contentsoyadi;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Soyadınız',
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                          child: const Text('Update'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            clickUpdate(_AdContr.text, _SoyadContr.text);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
```

**If above solution not work then try to use StreamBuilder() instead of FutureBuilder(). it will work and focuse without any problem.**

Comment: My main problem is that when I clicked the form, the keyboard shows up and closes immediately. It can be seen on the following video.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yNH5dPkP1U

Comment: hi after watching your video and code, i have updated my answer continue with bold text. please check

Comment: Hi First of all thanks for your helps. It tried but didnot work.I used onFieldSubmitted. Because when I used onSubmitted it said "parameter 'onSubmitted' isn't defined."Thus I changed it. But didnot work. I set the autofocus: true, this time there was some warnings on the console such as:         beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection 
getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
  This warning displayed 4 times ten the keyboard focused. Best Regards

Comment: if possible first try to use my code as well your code without FutureBuilder for testing only and check that problem occurs or not

Comment: When I removed the Future builder and keep only on the  StreamBuilder  It is working and focussing without any problem

Comment: The problem is that the text field is OK but I should use the Futurebuilder. I am using firebase auth and I have collection in firestore which I am using to store the name surname and other info of the users which registered. The auth of firebase and the users collection is connected with the user id. I am taking the info of the userid of the user and write it as document id in users collection. The page that I am working on is for user to update their user info. So to birng their old info to the text field I guess I should use futurebuilder to get uid. Or is there any other way

Comment: you should create another method that will use futurebuild and waits for reponse and call that in "initstate()" method and in the widget override method use streambuilder that will return another "text loading or something else widget" until we don't get any response from that method and as we get response from that method. try to update it in streambuilder and then retrun your edittext widget.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example. Or a link which explain with details. I searched your suggestion on google but couldnt find direct example. Best Regards

Comment: till try to understand this question and answer "https://stackoverflow.com/a/55776197/7326905" because it has the same issue which using future object as well strembuilder. If you have still confusion then i'll try to give you an example. Thanks for accepting answer.

Comment: I couldnt solve it. I wrote a method which finds the user ID : userUi() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(user.uid);
  }    I called the method from initstate as @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userUi();

  }    and ı Used it in stream builder as StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('kitaplar')
                  .document(userUi())
                  .snapshots(), but it is giving me  this error type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: I solved the problem by passing the data from the users menu page. As I mentioned I have a page for logged in user. When user logged in he/she sees a special menu. On this menu there is a link for  update info page . From the logged in page I am passing the user id data to update info page.  what do you think about this solution :-) I tried and it worked. Do you think that this solution can be a problem later on or not

Comment: But what if user will not press that update menu? so the problem can be generated.

Comment: The person is only going to use this page may be he wants to change his/her name nickname or date of birth or something like that. When User regstered this page will appear to take the user information. And If uid available but name field empty the button will be save or if there is data in the  name field it will be update. There is no further page after this page then user can click any other page from the menu. I guess this will solve my problem. Thanks for your help. Have a nica day and nice coding.