# flutter how to make gridview show firebase data like buttons

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, stream-builder

I am trying to user Streambuilder to display gridview, but it return this error, I am calling the method classList() to container in scaffold body

database = FirebaseDatabase.instance

[image: Database Image]

I want to show classData, show 0,1,2..etc I want to show ('className','classSection' in one button per child) in gridview as RaisedButtons

I get this error when the code below is executed

```
I/flutter ( 5433): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5433): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePage#055be):
I/flutter ( 5433): The method 'split' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5433): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 5433): Tried calling: split("/")
I/flutter ( 5433): 
I/flutter ( 5433): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5433): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #1      DatabaseReference.child (file:///G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-2.0.3/lib/src/database_reference.dart:24:58)
I/flutter ( 5433): #2      _HomePage.classList (package:barcode_scan_example/home_page.dart:169:44)
I/flutter ( 5433): #3      _HomePage.build (package:barcode_scan_example/home_page.dart:265:30)
I/flutter ( 5433): #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3825:27)
I/flutter ( 5433): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3736:15)
I/flutter ( 5433): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
I/flutter ( 5433): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
I/flutter ( 5433): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
I/flutter ( 5433): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
I/flutter ( 5433): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #14     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2273:33)
I/flutter ( 5433): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
I/flutter ( 5433): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
I/flutter ( 5433): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
I/flutter ( 5433): #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:840:5)
I/flutter ( 5433): #23     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
I/flutter ( 5433): #24     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
I/flutter ( 5433): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
```

```
classList() {
    StreamBuilder(
        stream:
            database.reference().child('user').child(userUid).child('classData').orderByKey().onValue,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
              List<dynamic> list = map.values.toList();
              print("list is : $list");

              return GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemCount: list.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  print("print job ${list[index]["className"]}");
                  return Container(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Text(
                          "${list[index]["className"]}\n ${list[index]["classSection"]}"),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                "There's no Class registered in the system",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.grey),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )));
            }
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
```

the entire dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'make_class.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'qr_screen.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

enum ScaffoldType { student, lecturer }

ScaffoldType _scaffoldType = ScaffoldType.lecturer;

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  String barcode = "";
  String userUid;
  var userClass;



  Future<void> _signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final BaseAuth auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
      await auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userUi();
    setState(() async* {
      FirebaseDatabase database;
      database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
      database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
      database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
    });
  }

  Future reUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(user.uid);
    var userUid = user.uid;
    var userWho = await database
        .reference()
        .child('user')
        .child(userUid)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snapshot.value;
      var isL = data.values.toList();
      print(isL[1]);
      print(data.values);
      if (isL[1].toString().toLowerCase() == "true") {
        _scaffoldType = ScaffoldType.lecturer;
        print('lecturer');
      } else if (isL[1].toString().toLowerCase() == "false") {
        _scaffoldType = ScaffoldType.student;
        print("student");
      }
    });
//        print(userWho);
  }



  userUi() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(user.uid);
    return user.uid;
  }

  classList(userUid) {

    print(userUid);
    StreamBuilder(
        stream:
        database.reference().child('user').child(userUid).child('classData').orderByKey().onValue,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
              List<dynamic> list = map.values.toList();
              print("list is : $list");

              return GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemCount: list.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  print("print job ${list[index]["className"]}");
                  return Container(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      child: Text(
                          "${list[index]["className"]}\n ${list[index]["classSection"]}"),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "There's no Class registered in the system",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )));
            }
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    var userUid = userUi();
    reUser();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onPressed: () => _signOut(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 8.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 0, 35, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: buttonBelow(),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: buttonBelow2(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: scan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.camera,
              size: 35,
            ),
            elevation: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(child: classList(userUi()),),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buttonBelow() {
    if (_scaffoldType == ScaffoldType.lecturer) {
      return <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add_circle,
            semanticLabel: "Add Class",
            size: 45,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MakeClass()),
            );
          },
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180)),
        ),
        Text("Add Class")
      ];
    } else {
      return <Widget>[
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle,
              semanticLabel: "Add Class",
              size: 45,
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180)),
          ),
        ),
        Opacity(opacity: 0, child: Text("Add Class"))
      ];
    }
  }
  List<Widget> buttonBelow2() {
    if (_scaffoldType == ScaffoldType.lecturer) {
      return <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.blur_on,
            semanticLabel: "QRCode",
            size: 45,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QrScreen()),
            );
          },
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180)),
        ),
        Text("QRCode")
      ];
    }
  }

  Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode =
          'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is when we pass blank or null string in ".child()" method of firebase, it will give us split("/") error because internally it will try to split from string and get try to get data
from it.

Now the problem in your code is you are calling "classList(userUid)" in the widget override method before the data come from firebase userid with use of StreamBuilder() but the userUid is blank and as i said above,
firebase will give us split("/") error if we pass blank or null in that ".child()" method.

So the conclusion is we have to wait for firebase userid until we get it from async result because to get firebase userid which is async task and we have to wait for that until result come with using await keyword.

*So Here is the answer, how to do that:
You have to replace your body portion in widget with the use of future<> such as below:*

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onPressed: () => _signOut(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 8.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 0, 35, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: buttonBelow(),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: buttonBelow2(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: scan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.camera,
              size: 35,
            ),
            elevation: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
       future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           return new Container(child: classList(snapshot.data.uid));
         }
         else {
           return new Text('Loading...');
         }
       },
      ),
    );
}
```

Also the best practice is that you have to get firebase userid only in "initState()" method which will call only once during lifecycle. so declare "FirebaseUser user" globally in your class and then call your "userUi()"
in only "initState()" method.

Comment: it didn't work, after digging it seem that userUid isn't getting passed cause it's generated from async method and stream builder is not async and when I make streambuild async method it doesn't work

Comment: please post your whole class to check from where  userUid is being assigned and from where classList() method called with streambuilder

Comment: I added the entire dart file, this my second ever full code I wrote the first one was command shell java 2 years ago :D soo don't mind the crazy sh!t happing in it. and sorry for the delay stackoverflow does not update inbox without refresh so I didn't notice for sometime.

Comment: I forget to say I got it to say Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' rather than null by passing in it through parameters

Comment: thank you I don't get error anymore , good to know I need future builder to pass future to normal method. but I encountered problem the method classList won't show anything just make internal call http://txt.do/1dsp6

Comment: move your all code within this block "builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {}" into the "new Container()" where we call "child: classList(snapshot.data.uid)".

Comment: I don't understand how to move builder to container , I tried moving but builder is not defined in container.

Comment: did u find solution ?

Comment: I have solved it by removing the variable list,map and made it to snapshot.data.snapshot.value in each call

Answer (score 1):

`The method 'split' was called on null.`
This type of exceptions occurs whenever you are referencing a path that doesn't exist. So make sure the path of your firebase database is correct.